# Greed for reps (and not a spirit of service) guides me. Am I a "normal" user?

Tags: discussion

The plain truth is that there is no particularly strong desire in me to "help others" by answering their answers, but simply to increase my reputation. In that sense, I am a greedy person when it comes to reputation and badges. I want more, quick, fast, always looking for low-hanging fruits.

Am I a "normal" Stack Exchange user?

---

**NOTE:** this is not a duplicate, because I am not interested on how to avoid gamification, but on how widespread it is. If this should be closed because is too broad/primarily opinion based, then closed it based on such condition, and not because it's a duplicate (which is not).

Comment: You're a [that what we are not allowed to call anyone](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281787/it-s-time-to-retire-the-term-rep-whore). Yes, you show often observed behavior.... nothing to worry about.

Comment: Yes, perfectly "normal".

Comment: Define normal. You're certainly not alone or in a minority.

Comment: What is your motivation for increasing your reputation? What do you plan to do with it?

Comment: I do wonder though what you want to do with the reputation once you have it. Say you get 10k, that unlocks a bunch of moderation tools. But moderation doesn't award any reputation, you see. So in your own description, you'd get reputation to then do ... what with it?

Comment: I'd wager many doctors care more about the $$$ than about the rewarding feeling of making people healthy.

Comment: Why do you think rep exists in the first place! Every human being does things out of self-interest. Everybody. Some people claim they prefer to help others than themselves, but actually they enjoy the feeling they get when they help others. This is perfectly normal and natural.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Getting philosophical here, but at what point does altruism stop being selfish when you can explain away every selfless action as being selfish by saying "The feeling that they get when doing $x".

Comment: @Magisch: It doesn't :) That's what I'm saying. A person performs altruistic actions because they want to, and they want to because their brain considers the resulting feeling to be a reward response. That's ultimately acting out of self-interest, no matter how you spin it. It just so happens that the side effect is other people are helped, which is nice. The same is true on SO; it's just that some people need the rep as a reward, and others get the same effect simply from internalising their joy at having answered/edited/reviewed/whatever.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, by all means you are *normal*, in terms of this service.

Whether your contributions being useful and not harmful is another question  (which nobody actually interested in).

Answer (score 3):

Depends on how you define "Normal". There are a lot of users like you, certainly. So you have good company.

Lusting after rep is not generally discouraged or forbidden, so do what you want as long as you keep posting useful content and don't litter the site with useless stuff, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

As reputation is some kind of a measure of how much you helped, hunting reputation is somehow related with hunting people whom you could help.
**Gamification** is a strong tool which Stack Overflow implemented to motivate to help. This mechanism is used for making other people's life easier - you are rewarded with reputation for everything that might be useful in the future, so nothing to worry about!